# Why did Nala Se care about how many clone lives Anakin saved in "Shadow of Malevolence"?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, character-development

At the end of "Shadow of Malevolence" (Season 1, Episode 3) from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Kaminoan healer Nala Se (one of the original engineers of clones) says to Anakin:

> General Skywalker, I wanted to thank you for your valiant effort today. Do not take the lives you saved lightly.

However, "the lives [he] saved" were almost entirely (not counting Nala Se, it should be entirely) clone lives, and Se is also quoted as saying (straight from Wookieepedia):

> You were created in our laboratories. You are Kaminoan property.
>
> -- Nala Se, to CT-5555 <sup>[src](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fugitive)</sup>

Per Wookieepedia:

> She held no regard for the lives of her clone creations beyond their usefulness to Kamino and the Galactic Republic.[9] From Nala Se's point of view, clones were disposable assets and the property of their creators.

So why does Se suddenly care about the lives of the clones to the extent that she is willing to sacrifice her own?

Comment: those slaves were valuable property. Just because she is glad they were saved, doesn't mean she is glad they were saved for any reason other than they were resources to be used and represented an investment

Answer (score 7):

She did care, but something made her change her mind later on.

Looking at [the chronological order of The Clone Wars episodes](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder), it can be noticed that *Shadow of Malevolence* takes place in an early stage of the conflict. All the later appearances of Nala Se, however, are set towards the end of the war. It seems that in the beginning she felt deeply towards the creations she had participated in with herself. She even defied death and didn't want to abandon the Kaliida Shoals Medical Center, which was about to be destroyed by General Grievous.

> **Clone Medical Officer:** It looks as though Skywalker has failed. He's
>   lost almost half his ships. We should go, Madame.
>
> **Nala Se:** I will stay.
>
> *The Clone Wars: Shadow of Malevolence*

It is also possible that she only recognized the "credit-value" of the 60,000 wounded clone troopers, but it is unlikely that she had been willing for die for that reason.

Later during the Clone Wars, Nala Se's attitude changed dramatically, as described in the question. Even though she was one of the chief engineers of the clones, she might have originally been unaware of the whole project and the true purpose of the Clone Army. Maybe it was only later revealed to her by the Kaminoan Prime Minister Lama Su.

It may also be worth noticing that in *Shadow of Malevolence* she was stationed on a Republic medical facility, as in the latter episodes she's on her "home ground" on Kamino, which might have had some impact in her behavior.

Comment: Nala Se was one of the key engineers for Order 66. She new, but she thought it was for rogue Jedi. Also, you seem to be proving to me that she is split on this.